# IB_DESIGNABLE build failed when using class from within a framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, interface-builder, xcode6

I created a new embedded framework. Within the framework I created a class called "WBButton", which is a subclass of UIButton.  I have set the IB_DESIGNABLE and added IBInspectable attributes to allow configuration through Interface builder, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html).

It works fine when I test it from within my framework (by adding a sample .xib and placing the button on the screen), but when adding the custom button to a nib located on the project which contains the framework, I get a "Build Failed" message next to the "Designables" (see below).

Also, what does "Module" mean in Interface builder?

[image]

Comment: It's now the end of 2015 and IB_DESIGNABLE and IBInspectable are still extremely flakey. I have a very large project and spent many hours implementing this nonsense and ten times as many hours trying to work around the bugs. I have given up numerous times. Hopefully I will now give up for good and leave it to rot! Thanks oh marvellous xcode coders!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 6 has a bug that breaks `IB_DESIGNABLE` classes defined in static library or framework. The same is with CocoaPods which use static library for all Pods.

Comment: This also fails if the class is included within the project and not in a static library or framework.

Comment: @Cyupa this answer is one year old. I've heard that recently Xcode has some issues with IBDesignable on Swift projects.

Comment: This bug cost me half a day.  I was trying to use TTTAttributedLabel and it just would not work until I subclassed it as something like MyLabel : TTTAttributedLabel.

Comment: @ZackMorris you can try using `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile in case you use CocoaPods.

Comment: Weird I am experiencing this in XCode 8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an Xcode bug

**Temporary workaround:**

Create an empty category/extension in the target that contains the storyboard or nib you want to use the designable view in.

**Swift:**

```
extension CustomView {

}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
//.h
@interface CustomView (Category)

@end

//.m
@implementation CustomView (Category)

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andy's comment above is correct answer if you use CocoaPods and your custom library is not working, you need to uncomment use_frameworks! in your Podfile and "pod install" again.

Apparently the "IB_DESIGNABLE" is not recognized by XCode if you don't do this.